# <QuerySet [<Address: Shreyash>, <Address: Shreyash>]>": "Order.address" must be a "Address" instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I have model related to that form what I want is to when user click on submit button from go submit and save in database but here I got error so what to achieve is a single address got submit in that instead of all the address which is linked with whit model choice field so any idea how i can achieve that

here is my models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=False)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)


    def placeorder(self):
        self.save()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Address(models.Model):
    eighteen_choice = {
        ('Yes','Yes'),
        ('No','No')
    }
    phoneNumberRegex = RegexValidator(regex = r"^\d{10,10}$")
    pincodeRegex = RegexValidator(regex = r"^\d{6,6}$")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='address')
    reciever_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    phone_no = models.CharField(validators = [phoneNumberRegex], max_length = 10, blank=False)
    alt_phone_no = models.CharField(validators = [phoneNumberRegex], max_length = 10, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=state_choice, blank=False)
    pincode = models.CharField(validators = [pincodeRegex], max_length = 6, blank=False)
    eighteen = models.CharField(blank=False, choices=eighteen_choice, default='Yes', max_length=4 )
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    locality = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,editable=False)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

my views.py

```
class Checkout(View):
    def post (self, request,):
        user = request.user
        address = Address.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        ids = (list(request.session.get('cart').keys()))
        items = Item.get_items_by_id(ids)

        for item in items:
            order = Order(user=user, item=item, address=address, price=item.price)
            order.save()
        
        request.session['cart'] = {}

        return redirect('transactions:cart')
```

my html

```
<div class="modal-body">
           <form action="{% url 'transactions:checkout' %}" method="Post">
             {% csrf_token %}
                 #in that i want i want to user select a address instead of all his address 
                    with miltiple choice field
             <input type="submit" class="btn float-right btn-primary" value='Go Ahead'>
           </form>
          </div>
```

Comment: Are you using any django forms? If you do please share

Comment: no  i am not using django forms

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass one Address to an Order, I don't know how you are going to check out which address you will use but an easy way is to select the first address as the following:

```
 order = Order(user=user, item=item, address=address.first(), price=item.price)
```

Or probably if you have an address as default you can use the following:

```
address = Address.objects.filter(user=request.user, default=True)
```

Then you will get the default address of the user in case you have it defined in that way.

Comment: so acc to you there is no way to achieve that

Comment: Then you have to put all the addresses in the view and let the user select to what address he wants to send the order. Or use one of those address in an arbitrary way.

Comment: i used the second option where it take default address selected by use now its throwing error Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Address: Shreyash>]>": "Order.address" must be a "Address" instance.

Comment: Then you have to use `address.first()` in the order. As I shared in here.